# Is there any data structure in stl that can insert element in O(1) or O(log n) and I can write my own bin_search on it?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I need a data structure that can insert elements in O(1) or O(log n), and I can write my own binary search function on this data structure object? If there's no such data structure in the stl, how i can write my own?

Comment: Can you show how can I write a simple binary_search function on it?

Comment: Not clear what you want. Why `std::set` is not good?

Comment: @SergeyA An associative container may not be ideal if the goal is the try to implement a binary search. The `std::set` doesn't need a binary search applied to it and trying to perform a binary search on an `std::set` may be problematic since it doesn't have a random access iterator.

Comment: A `std::deque` has constant time insertion at the ends and `std::vector` has constant time insertion at `end` if you `reserve` enough ahead of time. Both are compatible with a binary search function.

Comment: I need insertion in any point of the structure.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it is not clear why OP needs binary search to begin with. That's why I am asking for clarification.

Comment: @SergeyA My comment is answering your question of "Why `std::set` is not good?".

Answer (score 2):

There is a container in the STL which has `O(1)` or `O(logn)` insertions and has the ability to do binary search (which requires random access). Its name is `std::deque`, though it does not have any inherent ordering so you have to provide the element order yourself.

```
// Fill a deque with elements
std::deque<int> deq{4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3};
// Sort it to satisfy binary search precondition
std::sort(deq.begin(), deq.end());
// Do your binary search here
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux hmm, well this is not that much of a question about what satisfies the `std::binary_search` conditions, as OP is planning to implement it themselves, and I assume without ruining its complexity. Furthermore, we should also hope `std::binary_search` maps to `std::find` for non-random access iterators.

Comment: That's fair. I just wanted to amend my first comment, since I was surprised to find that. But I guess it isn't relevant. I'll delete it.

Comment: `std::deque` doesn't have `O(logn)` insertions. If the position isn't the front or back then insertion is **linear** in the lesser of the distances to the beginning or end.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to learn some computer science basics.  I would suggesting using std::vector as the underlying data structure, so that you can focus on the higher level core service logic rather than low level underlying memory handling.  Based on a vector, you can implement a heap for O( log n ) insertions.  Vectors have random access iterators which is useful for access to the "middle" element of the collection for a divide-and-conquer algorithm such as binary search.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, You can use heap data structure, It takes O(Log n) in worst case, but in average case it takes o(1)

Comment: Random insertion and allows binary search were the requirements.